# How to insert date value as 20-Nov-1999 format("%d-%b-%Y") in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wanted to store date value as 20-Nov-2001 with Date type in mysql instead of YYYY-MM-DD format. what should i do?

Comment: Could you please show , what have you tried so far?

Comment: store as char or varchar - but of course then it's not a date and you will have to str_to_date whenever you need a comparison and it'll not index efficiently. Why not store in yyyy-mm-dd and present in dd-mmm-yyyy format.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You convert it in your app and store it as '1999-11-20', and on the way out if you need to display it as 20-Nov-1999 and don't want to reformat it in your app, you use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_date_field, '%d-%b-%Y') FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Thankyou Gordan Bobic that worked for me. I converted the input date to sql.Date and inserted it to the DB.